# How to add i18n feature in javascript file with python?

Tags: javascript, python, internationalization, pyramid, mako

I am using python, pyramid framework and mako template engine now.

I want to add i18n feature to my project and followed this guide to do:

> https://github.com/ddellaquila/pyramid_i18n_howto

It worked well with html and python files. But there are some source in my javascript files that I want to translate them, too.

I tried to write this code in the javascript file like wroten in html:

```
${_(u'中文')}
```

But it seems it doesn't know the **${_(** mark.

Then how to do?

Comment: It won't work. Translation strings will only work only if you declare them in templates or views but not external javascript files.